How to align two x-axes (twiny) in matplotlib?
I have written this code to plot two curves. I want to show the same y value for two x values (x values are related by some non-linear relation). The function that describes y can be written as a function of any of them, that is why I want to show both dependencies. The problem is that in the plot, x-axes are not aligned.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Energies in keV
# EPKA, Tdam, eff
FeValues = np.array([
    [80, 69, 42],
    [90, 78, 42],
    [100, 86, 42]
])
WValues = np.array([
    [150, 133, 30],
    [200, 177, 29],
    [250, 220, 29]
])

fig = plt.figure()
axPKA = fig.add_subplot()
axPKA.set_xlabel(r"$E_{PKA}$ (keV)")
axPKA.set_ylabel(r"$\overline{\xi}$ (%)")
axTdam = axPKA.twiny()
axTdam.set_xlabel(r"$T_{dam}$ (keV)")

axPKA.plot(FeValues[:, 0], FeValues[:, 2], label="Fe", marker="o")
axPKA.plot(WValues[:, 0], WValues[:, 2], label="W", marker="o")
axTdam.scatter(FeValues[:, 1], FeValues[:, 2], marker=".", color="red")
axTdam.scatter(WValues[:, 1], WValues[:, 2], marker=".", color="red")

axPKA.legend()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

As you can see below, only first and last points are aligned:

This question is similar to this one, but none of the solutions proposed there worked.
Edit: Just to be clear, I want the red dots to be placed above the corresponding blue/orange ones.
Edit 2: as @mozway suggested, since the relation between EPKA and Tdam is non-linear, it's impossible to align data properly. In addition (not mentioned before), the non-linear relation is different for FeValues and WValues, so at the end I decided not to use this kind of plots. It might be better to add the EPKA-Tdam relation in another plot.

You can align the x-axes with Axes.sharex:
axTdam = axPKA.twiny()
axTdam.sharex(axPKA)

Output:

edited question
What you want is not possible, your data is not aligned
Demonstration, let's scale the Xs on [0, 1]:
all_data = np.vstack([FeValues, WValues])

MIN = all_data[:, :2].min(0)
MAX = all_data[:, :2].max(0)
Xs = (all_data[:, :2] - MIN)/(MAX-MIN)

print(Xs)
[[0.         0.        ]
 [0.05882353 0.05960265]   #
 [0.11764706 0.11258278]   # the points are
 [0.41176471 0.42384106]   # NOT aligned
 [0.70588235 0.71523179]   #
 [1.         1.        ]]


That is not what I was exactly looking for. I want the red dots to be placed above the corresponding blue/orange ones. I will clarify the question.

@Abel I see, then it is unfortunately not possible, your data is not linearly aligned (see update)

Thanks :) A workaround that I'm thinking about is setting x-axes ticks and ranges manually and remove axTdam.scatters (I put them because of the linked question). I really want to use both axes, so this might be the best option.
